# Своя рассылка на PHP

Tags: php, email

У меня есть таблица (MySQL), в которой хранятся записи с электронной почтой. Мне нужно сделать рассылку сообщений моим пользователям. Посоветуйте, как это лучше сделать. С какими сложностями (лёгкостями) я столкнусь. Есть ли уже готовые примеры (аналоги)? Что вы вообще можете посоветовать по этому вопросу? Всем буду очень признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю речь идёт о использовании [crontab](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron). Где-то на сервере должен лежать php-файл, который запустившись произведёт рассылку. Файл должен обладать правами 705, в его самой первой строчке (до "< ?php") должен быть указан путь к интерпретатору, напр. "#!/usr/local/bin/php". Если вы используете виртуальный хостинг, то лучше всего задать вопрос провайдеру.

Answer (score 1):

Можно и без кронтаба, если лично это дело контролировать. Это менее стабильно, но при отсутствии вариантов прокатит.

Делается страница с формой запуска, поля: Адрес для ответа, Заголовок, Сообщение, Стартовать с...

Форма отправляется аяксом. В хэндлере формы происходит следующее: берется следующий мыльник, отправляется письмо, возвращается результат вида "Отправлено на %EMAIL%". Если этот мыльник не последний, callback-функция меняет поле "стартовать с..." и шлет следующий запрос, иначе пишет что-то типа "отправка завершена". При таком раскладе если вдруг пропадет инет/рухнет сервер/еще что-то, форма останется на последнем запросе и его можно будет продолжить.

Для размышлений:

```
$num = intval(isset($_POST['num'])?$_POST['num']:0);
/* запрос "дайте следующее мыло" */
$em_res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM emails WHERE 1=1 LIMIT '.$num.', 1;');
if ($email = mysql_fetch_object($em_res)) {
  /* шлем письмо, докладываем о результатах */
  } else {
  echo 'Рассылка завершена';
  }
```

ЗЫ выделяю: **это костыль aka хак и так делать неправильно** =)

ЗЗЫ по готовым могу посоветовать [гугл](http://www.google.ru/search?q=%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82+%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B8+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:ru:official&client=firefox) , не от лени, но для понимания, что скриптов этих - легион.